# how can rotate the edge point of my 3d object in unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

[visualization of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyc3S.png)

Hi, I am new at unity and I want to rotate edge of my enemy object but I googled a lot and the only algos that I find is about rotating whole object. Like;

```
obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 30f, 90.0f), 0.0f);
```

it rotates whole object of course, but I dont know how to focus on just an edge. I just want to rotate it like a door opening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to do `transform.rotateAround`. You can specify which axis and the amount of degrees. Here is the link to the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Comment: what if I want to do this with a Mathf.PingPong(). I want rotateAround up to x = 90 and down to x = 0. do you have any suggestion?